# How to fix sonarlint warning for one line initialize?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
response.setPeopleHealth(new ArrayList<String>() {{
       for(HealthEnum e :HealthEnum.values()) { 
          add(e.getValue());
       }
      }})
```

sonarlint gives warning for this.

I tried to convert to singletone but it does not work with for, because it cant be added like arraylist.

Can i use lambda or stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters stop using the famous anti-pattern of `new ArrayList<String>() {{...`, than think about your problem to begin with, you have a array - need a `List`, thus:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(HealthEnum.values())
      .map(HealthEnum::getValue)
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

and pass this `ArrayList` where you want to, like:

```
response.setPeopleHealth(list);
```

Comment: Thank you. what about without defining a new list and setting directly?  `response.setPeopleHealth(lrrays.stream(HealthEnum.values())
      .map(HealthEnum::getValue)
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))`

Comment: @vegan of course, I was just providing an example to make it more clear

Comment: What about this `response.addToList(new ArrayList<String>() {{p.getCode(); data.getError(); }});`

Comment: @vegan this now is out of context, I don't really understand what you are doing, either way stop using that anti-pattern